# Is there a device independent way to open the maps application on a website?

Tags: html, url, web, url-scheme

When I look at the Apple's URL Scheme they advise to use the following url scheme:

```
http://maps.apple.com/?q=Mexican+Restaurant
```

The URL scheme for Android is:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=brighton&daddr=timbuktu
```

There are general URL schemes such as `tel://` and `mailto:` that just open the device default application. I know `maps://` does not work, so what would the best device independent way be?

Comment: To add to your pain, an iOS user may be using Google maps, not Apple maps.

Comment: You could build a redirect to intelligently send each platform to the appropriate URL

Answer (score 1):

Use Apple Maps links. Apple will automatically shoot Android users over to Google Maps since they don't have Apple Maps. This will then launch the default maps app on their device.

Google will load Google Maps with advertising to download Google Maps. It will not load the devices native maps app on iOS.

For a better user experience, use Apple Maps links.